# Navegação interna com JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu header:

```
<header>
...

<div id="header-reserva" class="cf">
   <a href="#header-reserva-iframe" class="scroll">Reserve aqui!</a>
</div>

...

<iframe id="header-reserva-iframe" src="http://www.meuiframe.com"></iframe>

</header>
```

O iframe está com display none, pois só quero que ele apareça quando o link for clicado. Para isso fiz um código em JQuery:

```
$("#header-reserva a").click(function() 
{
    $("#header-reserva-iframe").css('display', 'inherit');
});
```

O iframe é apresentado quando o link é clicado, mas o link não é direcionado para o iframe no primeiro clique, sendo necessário um segundo click para isso, ou seja, preciso que o link no primeiro click tanto mostre o iframe quanto navegue para o topo dele. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar isso para animar o scroll até o iframe

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#header-reserva-iframe").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O link aponta para o frame de fora (window). Para apontar para o iframe, use um `target`:

```
<a href="#" target="header-reserva-iframe" class="scroll">Reserve aqui!</a>
```

Para o `target` funcionar, acredito que você precisa de um `name` no iframe:

```
<iframe id="header-reserva-iframe" name="header-reserva-iframe" src="http://www.meuiframe.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Tentei mas não obtive resultado.

Comment: Tente colocar um name no iframe, igual ao id

Answer (score 0):

Tente forçar a página a ir pra div assim:

```
$("#header-reserva a").click(function() 
{
    $("#header-reserva-iframe").css('display', 'inherit');
    window.location.hash = '#header-reserva-iframe';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lembre-se que o código jQuery deve rodar só depois que a página terminar de carregar o DOM, que é a árvore de elementos do documento. Com isso você não precisa forçar o navegador a fazer o scroll até o elemento.

```
$(function(){ // Aguarda o DOM ser carregado
    $("#header-reserva a").click(function() {
        $("#header-reserva-iframe").show(); // Troquei o .css() por .show() só pra ficar mais legível
    });
});
```